# PWA-Firebase: Data cached in Offline mode is not getting uploaded on Firebase when reconnected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a progressive web app, which will have a form(to be filled by the farmers).

I am using [localforage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) to cache my data in offline mode.

- When connectivity is available:
  The data fetched from the form is pushed on Firebase.
- When connectivity is unavailable:
  The data should get cached in localforage cache.

**Once reconnected, the cached data should get pushed to Firebase, but it doesn't.**

Here's the code:

**Offline Code**

```
 const state = {
          isConnected: false,
        };

    const connectionRef = firebase.database().ref('.info/connected');

        const localforageToFirebase = messages => {
          if(messages && state.isConnected && firebase.auth.currentUser ){
            while( messages.length){
              pushToFirebase( messages.shift() );
            }
            localforage.setItem( 'offlineMessages', [] );
          }
        };

        connectionRef.on( 'value', snap => {
          state.isConnected = snap.val();
          localforage.getItem( 'offlineMessages' ).then( localforageToFirebase );
        });
```

**Push to Firebase**

```
const pushToFirebase = message => {
    firebase.database().ref('messages').push({ message });
  };


const messageFormSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const message = $( '#message' ).val();
    if( state.isConnected ){
      pushToFirebase( message );
    }
    else{
      localforage.getItem( 'offlineMessages' )
      .then( messages => {
        const msg = messages ? [...messages,message] : [message]; 
        localforage.setItem( 'offlineMessages', msg );
      });
    }
    $( '.message-form' ).trigger( 'reset' );
  }
```

I am new to PWA and Firebase & don't know where exactly the issue is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What precisely doesn't work? Does your `connectionRef.on( 'value'` callback trigger when you set a breakpoint in it? What is `localforageToFirebase`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, there was an issue in the user authentication function, due to which the cached data wasn't getting pushed on to Firebase when reconnected.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, there's another issue regarding the caching of static & remote files. Static files get cached, but remote files aren't(Edited the question for the same).